Mocking Airflow ImapHook class
I wrote an Airflow Dag that uses the ImapHook to log into an email account and retrieve some mails. I'm trying to write unit tests for this dag, but I'm having issues on mocking the ImapHook class.
For the mocks to work, I need to mock the mail_client attribute that it's inside ImapHook Class, however, so far I'm unable to accomplish this mock.
The part of the code that I'm trying to mock:
    with ImapHook(imap_conn_id="imap") as hook:
        try:
            hook.mail_client.select("INBOX", readonly=True)
            _, data = hook.mail_client.search(
                "iso-8859-1",
                DATE_SEARCH_CRITERIA,
                SUBJECT_SEARCH_CRITERIA,
            )

With:
@patch("file_where_i_import_the_hook.ImapHook")
I can mock the Hook, but when trying to mock the return_value of it, I get the error not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0) on the _, data of the search function.
The mocks that I tried:
mock.return_value.select.return_value = ("OK", b"1")
mock.return_value.search.return_value = ("OK", [b"1"])

If I try this
mock.select.return_value = ("OK", b"1")
mock.search.return_value = ("OK", [b"1"])

or this
mock.mail_client.select.return_value = ("OK", b"1")
mock.mail_client.search.return_value = ("OK", [b"1"])

I get the same error.
It appears that I'm unable to get to the mail_client object to mock it.
I also tried to use @patch.object to mock __enter__ and get_conn also without success. If mail_client was available on the class ImapHook, I think that the patch.objecton it would work, however if I try @patch.object(ImapHook,"mail_client") I get the error:
AttributeError: <class 'airflow.providers.imap.hooks.imap.ImapHook'> does not have the attribute 'mail_client'

The alternative would be to implement the use directly of the Imap library without using the airflow hook. However, I would like to figure out where my mock is wrong or if this is some airflow witchcraft that I need to understand.
